# How can I prevent to display FCM notification on Flutter app background?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

```dart
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}
```

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
```

I can display background notifications with these snippet codes. But is there any way to not display some specific notification in the background?

For example I don't want to display notifications with `data = {title = "call"}`

Comment: found the solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 5):

from the sender device u have to send data only notification

```dart
await http.post(
          Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'key=$serverKey',
          },
          body: jsonEncode(
            <String, dynamic>{
              'data': <String, dynamic>{
                'id': '2',
                'status': 'done'
              },
              'to': userToken,
              "collapse_key": uid,
            },
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Data only notifications will not show up in iOS if the device is rebooted. It will show again if the user opens the app.

Comment: @PeakGen The purpose of data-only notification is not to show up, I tested this approach and it worked on android, I am not sure about IOS.

Answer (score -3):

add conditions in your _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler like

```
    Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

if(message.data["title"]=="Call")
{
// show nothing
}
else
{
// show notifications
}
      
    }
```

Comment: in ```_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler``` function we don't implement anything to display notification, automatically displayed if we pass the empty function to FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage

Comment: this method is not related to this topic if you don't write this function at all the notification will appear! so it is not helpful...